# A simple client-server application

Tags: c#, azure, client-server, windows-server-2008, tcpclient

I have created 2 console applications:

Server:

```
TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("serverIP"), 8001);
while (true)
{
   myList.Start();
   Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
   byte[] b = new byte[100];
   int k = s.Receive(b);
   for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));
   s.Send(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
   Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");
   s.Close();
}
```

Client:

```
while (true)
{
   TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
   tcpclnt.Connect(serverIP, 8001);
   Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();
   byte[] ba = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(Console.ReadLine());
   Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");
   stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
   byte[] bb = new byte[100];
   int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);
   for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));
   tcpclnt.Close();
```

}

When both applications run on my machine they work fine, but when I run server application on Windows Server 2008 (Windows Azure) I have an error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond

On the statement: `tcpclnt.Connect(serverIP, 8001);`

What should I configure in order to run my Apps?

Should I change something here ?

[image]`
[image]

Comment: It may sound obvious, but did you check if the server's firewall is dropping the connection?

Comment: @chris, May I ask you to provide some details how to do it ? I attach the firewall screen to my post. Please check.

Comment: @chris I have created a Firewall rule for my application to allow connections.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to create a 'EndPoint' for you application in the Azure portal.

Navigate to your VM within the Azure portal and select 'ENDPOINTS', create using the port you expect the service to run on.

Also, as in your screenshot ensure you have the port open in your windows firewall of the VM.

Comment: I have created an endpoint: protocol - TCP, private port - 8001, public port - 8001.